# @ControllerAdvice (REST 404) - wrong exceptions thrown

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm using Spring MVC 3.2.9 and I'm currently working on global error handling for the application. My error handling class looks like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoSuchRequestHandlingMethod(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

        //Some code

        return new ResponseEntity(ex, headers, status);
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

        //Some code

        return new ResponseEntity(ex, headers, status);
    }
}
```

One of my controllers looks like this (simplified)

```
@Controller
public class FormController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/modules/admin/form/add/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void createForm(@RequestBody Form form) {
        //add form
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/modules/admin/form/{formId}/details/field/add/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void createField(@PathVariable Long formId, @RequestBody Field field) {
        //add field
    }
}
```

I'm trying to raise 404 error by triggering NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException hoping that my error handling class will catch it and return ResponseEntity as stated. But this is what is happening instead:

If I make request from client like this:

```
/modules/admin/form/addfsdfadf/
```

it should trigger said exception since this mapping does not exist, right? But instead HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException is thrown and handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported is called.

Another example:

```
/modules/admin/form/1232313423/details/field/addhfddfhfghsdfhs/
```

this mapping also does not exist but instead it's completely bypassing my error handling mechanism and I'm getting plain old Tomcat 404 page in the response (pure html).

I have tested this and it seems that number of characters in the request somehow determines which kind of response I'll get and in my case they are both wrong.

Can anyone figure out what is going on here? Is this a bug or expected behaviour? Am I doing this wrong?

What I actually want is handle 404's without getting default Tomcat page or my own default page. This is REST controller and if 404 occurs I want to get JSON response...is this possible?

Comment: See if this answer helps: [Handle default 404 exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968462/how-to-add-model-attributes-to-the-default-error-page/50968463#50968463)